# What is the ThePreStubAMD64 function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance

I'm profiling my application in Visual Studio and the function with the most exclusive samples taken is ThePreStubAMD64.

(I'm using Performance Explorer to review my CPU Sampling report.)

However, I can't find much for documentation on what this is or what is actually calling this function.  The Function Details view in Performance explorer isn't much help with locating the exact line that is calling this function.  (Maybe I'm doing it wrong :-) )

It's being called from multiple functions, but the exact location is a mystery.

Any idea on what this is and how it is being called would be helpful.  Or any help with the Performance Explorer and tracking down code (Correlating the function name in the Function Details view ithe the Function Code View would be helpful).

Comment: Avoid considering the startup cost of your program in your profiling results.  There isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: @Hans - Actually I pause the profiler until the program is started. (20 seconds in roughly), but these methods are called for the first time after that.  Perhaps I should do a warm up of the functions and then profile.  However, I want to profile based on what the users would experience, not just "the optimal case".

Comment: Hey Chris,  take a look at this regarding startup time. You can do something about it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656914.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an internal method to .NET for JIT.  It is a little harder to find any docs on it, because it is the 64 Bit version of PreStubWorker.  Search for that and you will find lots of information.